# A Mocked repository returns null - Springboot JUnit Mockito

Tags: mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

Im trying to use the save from my repository EmpresaRepository, but it returns null, heres my repository
[heres my repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHbRY.png)
[and this is my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iage4.png)

[And this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YucK8.png)

Comment: Tip from long-time SO user: Inlining your code and output samples, instead of just linking them, will increase the odds that someone is going to answer. It’s less hassle for me as a reader and I can see all relevant info together.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour.

By using `@MockBean` you create and add a Mock of your EmpresaRepository into the `ApplicationContext`.
This means you execute the `::save()` Method of your mock which returns `null` bey default.

Rule of thumb: **Never Mock the thing you want to test.**

The test should work if you replace the `@MockBean` annotation with `Autowired`.

---

Btw. **please don't post screenshots of your code**. It's annoying to switch between different tabs and also I'm not able to copy parts of your code.